# ¿Cuál es la manera más eficiente de eliminar múltiples registros con archivos relacionados en Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

1. Tengo un método **observador** "**deleted**" en mi modelo que elimina una imagen relacionada.

```
 public function deleted(Profile $profile)
 {
    $this->deleteProfilePhoto($profile);
 }
```

2. Tengo una **schedule** que elimina los modelos que no cumplen una determinada condición.

```
Profile::whereNull('parametro')->get()->each(function($profile) {
    $profile->delete();
});
```

3. Sin embargo, creo que esto no sería tan eficiente si tuviese miles de registros ya que estaría haciendo una consulta a la base de datos por cada iteración.

**Nota:** Con la implementación actual necesito llamar a cada modelo individualmente para usar el método **delete()** y el evento **deleted()** sea activado y los archivos se eliminen, de lo contrario no se eliminarían.

**¿Hay alguna manera de eliminar múltiples modelos con sus respectivos archivos y hacer esto más eficiente?**** Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

en tu schedule podrias usar DB [laravel DB](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements) para hacer una simple query como esta:

```
DB::table('profiles')->whereNull('parametro')->delete();
```

---

**actualizacion**

buenas buscando en la documentacion, existe [Prune models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#pruning-models)
el cual dice:

> This method can be useful for deleting any additional resources associated with the model, such as stored files

creando una funcion como esta en tu modelo `Profile`:
(eliminar los que tengan parametro null)

```
public function prunable()
{
    return static::whereNull('parametro');
}
```

luego con la funcion `pruning` puedes llamar a tu funcion `deleteProfilePhoto` como por ejemplo:
(donde $this en si es el modelo, puedes pasar el id $this->id)

```
protected function pruning()
{
    $this->deleteProfilePhoto($this);
}
```

ahora en el app\console\kernel.php
agrega en la funcion schedule puedes llamar al comando para ejecutarlo.

```
{
    $schedule->command('model:prune',[
        '--model' => Profile::class
    ])->daily();
}
```

espero que te pueda ayudar esta info.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, sin embargo, esto no me funcionaría si quiero que el evento deleted() se active para eliminar archivos relacionados al modelo. **He actualizado la nota y mi pregunta**

Comment: hola buenas,  he actualizado mi respuesta igualmente.